# Facebook login reset password

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, authentication

I have developed an app needed login with Facebook and everything is so fine. I use some delegates as below to let user to login.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error
```

After user login firstly, my app will login automatically in next time. So everything is OK. If the user changes their password, my app will still login automatically. I think the app should call handleError to stop login automatically. But my app didn't do this. It seems that the app will save a plist file in local file and then to read the plist file to get the information to login with Facebook again.

I hope my app will present login view again if the user resets their password.

Answer (score 0):

Your app uses a token and not the user password to login. The token can only be used by your app (in combination with the Facebook app ID).

You app never receives the user password which makes is more secure.

This is done so that a user can remove access to their account on a per app basis. also changing their password will not log them out of all their apps. So there is no way for you app to know that the users changed their password.